# How do you actually use an astronomical interferometer to measure small distances?

Tags: astronomy, interferometry, telescopes

The question in the title might be too broad, so for definiteness we can focus on the [Michelson stellar interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_stellar_interferometer) which, as I understand it, is more or less just two telescopes some distance apart. For whatever reason, I haven't been able to find a straightforward explanation of what it actually measures - by which I mean what is the experimentally controlled variable (the angle of the telescopes? the distance between them? the position on a screen?) and how this measurement is used to find, say, the diameter of a star that a single telescope can't resolve.

All the books and online sources I've found simply explain the general phenomenon of interference fringes (which I understand) and skip to saying that it can be used to observe very small objects in the sky. My overall goal with this is to understand modern interferometers like the Event Horizon Telescope, but for now I have a concrete question: could some give a mathematical explanation of how one can use two telescopes to measure the diameter of a star?

Answer (score 0):

The extent of the spatial coherence of the light from a source with some angular extent, depends on the angle subtended by the source.

You can see this if  you assume that each point on the surface of the star is an independent light source and light you receive at a point is the sum of all these sources. The [van Cittert-Zernike Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Cittert%E2%80%93Zernike_theorem) says that the wavefront of the incoming light is coherent over an area given by
$$
A= \frac{D^2\lambda^2}{d^2\pi}
$$
where  $D$ is the distance to the star, $d$ is its diameter (so $d/D$ is the angle subtended by the star). If you interfere light that arrives at a point with another part of the wavefront within this area surrounding the point you get intereference fringes. If the second part of the wavefront is  outside the area around the first point  it is incoherent with that at the first point.  So if  you make your collecting mirrors too far apart there are no fringes.  From this you can find $\theta$.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but honestly I was looking for a bit more detail. For example: how does the formula for the area of coherence arise (it's not in your link)? Does this mean that the variable we control is the distance between telescopes, and measure the point at which we lose coherence?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what Michaelson did to measure the diameter  of stars.  He increased the distance between the collecing mirrors until the fringes washed out.  Then he used the coherence length formula. Actually for Sirius he kept separating even after the fringes vanished and saw that the  fringes came back for a while becuse Sirius is a double star.   I found lectures at https://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/10UCSC/Lecture_3a_Interferometry.pdf which describe some of this.